# Spark - speed up cartesian product

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, combinations

Is there a proper way to speed up the cartesian product between two datasets? I'm using a dataset of 350k elements and I would like to get the combinations (n takes 2) of it.

I used the classical strategy for finding 2-combinations in Spark:

```
words_comb = dataset.cartesian(dataset).filter(lambda x: x[0] < x[1])
```

I'm using the Databricks framework and it is takig more than 45 min to work out (at 45 min the spark driver stops in Databricks...). We can all agree on the fact that the **bottleneck** on this specific problem is the **cartesian product** of the dataset, which has a time complexity of O(n^2).

Is there a way to improve this? Is there a better approach to this problem?

(thank-you)

Comment: There is an [article](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6747/how-do-i-get-a-cartesian-product-of-a-huge-dataset.html) on the databricks forum that may help you.

Comment: @Jeremy Thank you.

Comment: Problem will be O(n^2) no matter what you do so in isolation this question is a bit pointless. Generating all combinations suggests brute force approach, so I'd focus on improving overall algorithm.

Comment: I concur with @user8371915

Comment: What do you want to do with the Cartesian product? A general way to reduce the complexity would be to determine (based on your use case) what are the values that do not need to be generated and to filter them out before calling the cartesian method.

Comment: I need to build a graph G=(N, F) where F(n) is the function that has as image the subset S of the words s which have edit_distance(n,s) = 1. to do this I hae started with all the words combinations and successively i filtered all the word pairs which didn't satisfied the contraint of edit_distance = 1. I haven't found a good strategy to filter the dataset before starting the cartesian yet.

Comment: @Jeremy I followed the instructions in the link, still stops after 2 hours of processing

Comment: What is the average size of the word in kilobytes?

Comment: @user8371915 I honestly have no idea! anyway [this](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words/blob/master/words_alpha.txt) is the dictionary I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It's possible to get rid of Cartesian product, without using a special data structure.

I will demonstrate the method by an example with pyspark

Suppose you have a data set of (user, query).

input:

users_queries_rdd = sc.parallelize([
     ('u1', 'q1'), ('u1', 'q2'), ('u1', 'q3'), ('u1', 'q4'),
     ('u2', 'q2'), ('u2', 'q4'), ('u2', 'q5'),
     ('u3', 'q1'), ('u3', 'q2'), ('u3', 'q4')
 ])

You would like to count the occurrences of 2 queries for different users.

expected output:
[(('q4', 'q2'), 3),
 (('q5', 'q2'), 1),
 (('q3', 'q1'), 1),
 (('q5', 'q4'), 1),
 (('q4', 'q1'), 2),
 (('q3', 'q2'), 1),
 (('q2', 'q1'), 2),
 (('q4', 'q3'), 1)]
```

### Method 1 - using Cartesian product:

```
pair_queries_count_rdd = users_queries_rdd\
.cartesian(users_queries_rdd)\
.filter(lambda line: line[0] > line[1])\
.filter(lambda line: line[0][0] == line[1][0])\
.map(lambda line: (line[0][1], line[1][1]))\
.map(lambda line: (line, 1))\
.reduceByKey(add)
```

### Method 2 - getting rid of Cartesian product:

```
pair_queries_count_rdd_no_cartesian = users_queries_rdd\
                        .map(lambda line: (line[0], [line[1]]))\
                        .reduceByKey(add)\
                        .map(lambda line: tuple(combinations(line[1], 2)))\
                        .flatMap(lambda line: [(x, 1) for x in line])\
                        .reduceByKey(add)
```

### Explanation:

### method 1:

1.1 .cartesian(users_queries_rdd)
    Creates a Cartesian product between the rdd to itself.
    It generates n^2 combinations.

1.2 .filter(lambda line: line[0] > line[1])
    If (q1,q2) is included, then (q2,q1) will be filtered out.

1.3 .filter(lambda line: line[0][0] == line[1][0])
    Group queries by user (aggregation).

1.4  .map(lambda line: (line[0][1], line[1][1]))
    Omit the user column. only query pairs will remain.

1.5 .map(lambda line: (line, 1))
    Map (q[i], q[j]) to ((q[i], q[j]), 1) for every line

1.6 .reduceByKey(add)
    Count number of occurrences, for each query pair.

### method 2:

2.1 .map(lambda line: (line[0], [line[1]]))
    Map (u[i], q[j]) to (u[i], [q[j]]) for every line (the query is encapsulated into a list)

2.2 .reduceByKey(add)
    For each user, create a list with all of their queries.

2.3 .map(lambda line: tuple(combinations(line[1], 2)))
    For every user, omit the user column, and create combinations of all of their queries

2.4 .flatMap(lambda line: [(x, 1) for x in line])
    Flat map will flat all of the keys: (q[i],q[j]) mapped to ((q[i],q[j]), 1)

2.5 .reduceByKey(add)
    Count number of occurrences, for each query pair.

We assume that the number of queries per user is relatively small (a constant number).
Therefore, the efficiency of method 2 is O(n)

This assumption is essential, due to the use of iter.combinations function for each user.

In the majority of practical cases, method 2 is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to build a graph G=(N, F) where F(n) is the function that has as image the subset S of the words s which have edit_distance(n,s) = 1. to do this I hae started with all the words combinations and successively i filtered all the word pairs which didn't satisfied the contraint of edit_distance = 1.

You approach is ridiculously inefficient. With *n* words of average length string *s* is more or less *O(n<sup>2</sup> s<sup>2</sup>)* (*n<sup>2</sup>*  `edit_distance` calls). At the same time you data is tiny (4.1MB according to [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115228/spark-speed-up-cartesian-product?noredirect=1#comment83235822_48115228)) and distributed processing, with its overhead, is not very useful. You should rethink your approach.

My advice is to use efficient lookup structure (for example [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [BWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform)) which can facilitate efficient search with mismatches. Build index, with a whole dataset, if needed use threading to parallelize search.